# how to run one query at a time?

Tags: php, mysql

i make a php page and i want if data post then queries run for this i use isset function but not worked for me it always run three queries but i want to run one query at a time how i do this?here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['fromdate'])){
                $fromdate=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['fromdate']));
        echo $select="select b.email AS Email from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' and b.created_on>='".$fromdate."' group by r.buyer_id";
 $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
$record=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $recepients = $recepients + $record;                    
}
if(isset($_POST['todate'])){
$todate=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['todate']));
echo $select1="select b.email AS Email from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' and b.created_on>='".$todate."' group by r.buyer_id";
$res1 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select1) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
                $record1=mysqli_num_rows($res1);
                $recepients = $recepients + $record1;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['fromdate']) && isset($_POST['todate'])){ 
            $fromdate=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['fromdate']));
            $todate=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['todate'])); 
                echo $select2="select b.email AS Email from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' and b.created_on BETWEEN '".$fromdate."' AND  '".$todate."' group by r.buyer_id";
$res2 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select2) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
                $record2=mysqli_num_rows($res2);
                $recepients = $recepients + $record2;
            }
```

and here is my array:

```
Array ( [events] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [fromdate] => [todate] => February 11, 2014 2:55 PM [description] => [subject] => [fromname] => [replyto] => [senddatetime] => [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles [message] => [submit_skip] => Continue )
```

and when i show the queries then give bad result here is my queries

```
 select b.email AS Email from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='7' and b.created_on>='1970-01-01 12:00:00' group by r.buyer_id
 select b.email AS Email from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='7' and b.created_on>='2014-02-11 02:55:00' group by r.buyer_id
 select b.email AS Email from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='7' and b.created_on BETWEEN '1970-01-01 12:00:00' AND '2014-02-11 02:55:00' group by r.buyer_id
```

Comment: use this is in if, elseif , else structure

Comment: Also, your code is pretty dense – think about breaking it up significantly - also, using $GLOBALS is pretty unusual, and using $_POST variables directly in SQL = you will get hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your array there is both `fromdate` and `todate` indexes. Thats why the 3 code blocks are executed. You are only checking for the index, you need to check the value also. ie.,not null. Also use the `if..else`. Here you can use the following,

```
//if both fromdate and todate are not null
if(isset($_POST['fromdate']) and $_POST['fromdate']!='' and isset($_POST['todate']) and $_POST['todate']!=''){
   //code
}
//if fromdate is not null
else if(isset($_POST['fromdate']) and $_POST['fromdate']!=''){
    //code
}
//if todate is not null
else if(isset($_POST['todate']) and $_POST['todate']!=''){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use !isset($_POST['todate'] on the first one for example.

```
if(isset($_POST['fromdate']) && !isset($_POST['todate']){
    // code
}
if(isset($_POST['todate']) && !isset($_POST['fromdate']){
    // code
} 
if(isset($_POST['fromdate']) && isset($_POST['todate'])){ 
    // code
}
```